# Android publish app with Google map 1.0

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I created a NEW android app with Google maps v1 and when I tried to publish it i see that Google map v1 is not sopported by Google . I there any way to publish my app with the v1?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer would be: No, unless you have generated a release api key before this service became deprecated.

Google doesn't provide keys for Google Map API V1, therefore unless you have already registered you application's release key with Google's API Console, AFAIK there is no way you could do it right now.

as mentioned in the comment, there are a lot of resources that will help you to port you API V1 implementation to API V2, you can take a look at this blog post I wrote on integrating Google Map API V2 in your application:

[Google Map API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: Here are two resources that might help you upgrade from v1 to v2:
(1) A discussion about parallels between the APIs - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/CGF5X1HMLuY
(2) A tutorial for the v2 API - http://ramsandroid4all.blogspot.com/2013/03/google-maps-android-api-v2.html
Good luck!